# Openpyxl Unable to edit data in large excel files (Keep the original formatting of cells like cell background)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Problem: I have to change few cells value in a excel and save it.

file details:
file size:80 mb
no of sheets: 12
average columns per sheet: 2800
average rows per sheet:  1200

Tried solution:

- `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_path)`
- *issue with this is whenever i am trying this there is memory issue*
- cant use **read only** and **write only** as i have to update current excel sheet.

**Suggest other library if that solves this issue**